# Pass string to JavaScript Funtion on onclick event of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to pass a value on onclick event of a button so that javascript may update the value of hidden field. But I am unable to pass string to js function

JS

```
<script>
   function sethdnfiletype(filetype)
   {
       $("#hdnfiletype").val(filetype);
   }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btn1" runat="server" ToolTip="Upload Report"  OnClick="sethdnfiletype(// here I want to send a number like 1 or 2 or 3 //);" href="#uploadTOEFilePopup" data-toggle="modal" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589417/programmatically-click-a-webpage-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send values to a function using onclick, just pass them in as you would call a function usually.

```js
function clickHandler(amount) {
  alert('Clicked with ' + amount);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="clickHandler(123);">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Crazy thing is I am using the same code like you but mine is showing this error :CS1026: ) expected 
 
 <script>
       function sethdnfiletype(filetype)
       {
           
          alert(filetype);
       }
   </script>

 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUploadPurchaseTerms" runat="server"
  OnClick="sethdnfiletype(1);" />

I seriously dont know why is it expecting closing bracket here

Comment: oh it was happening because i was using onclick event rather thatn using onclientclick

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Bind allows you to set some default parameters and the `this` context. So you could do this: `sethdnfiletype.bind(this, 1);` which would pass in the value `1` to your function as the first parameter and the event as the second parameter.